# Pydantic v2 migration and string typecasting

Tags: python, pydantic

I'm tried to migrate my project to Pydantic v2 and tests fails on integer to string type conversation.

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Foo(BaseModel):
   bar: str


Foo(bar=1)
```

Code fails with exception:

```bash
ValidationError: 1 validation error for Foo
bar
  Input should be a valid string [type=string_type, input_value=1, input_type=int]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.3/v/string_type
```

However, Pydantic v1 succsessfully converts `1` to `'1'`

Is there a soft way to convert it without using `Foo(bar=str(1))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See: [*Documentation*](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/api/config/#pydantic.config.ConfigDict.coerce_numbers_to_str)

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, ConfigDict

class Foo(BaseModel):
    bar: str
    model_config = ConfigDict(coerce_numbers_to_str=True)

Foo(bar=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

> In pydantic V2, the following principle will govern when data should
> be converted in "lax mode" (strict=False):
>
> If the input data has a SINGLE and INTUITIVE representation, in the field's type, AND no data is lost during the conversion, then the
> data will be converted; otherwise a validation error is raised. **There
> is one exception to this rule: string fields** - virtually all data has
> an intuitive representation as a string (e.g. repr() and str()),
> therefore a custom rule is required: only str, bytes and bytearray are
> valid as inputs to string fields.

https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/blog/pydantic-v2/#strict-mode

> Some type conversion shown here is a significant departure from
> existing behavior, we may have to provide a config flag for backwards
> compatibility for a few of them, however pydantic V2 cannot be
> entirely backward compatible, see pydantic-core#152.

https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/blog/pydantic-v2/#conversion-table

Answer (score 0):

For quick migration, I used a `field_validator`, but I don't think that's a proper solution:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, field_validator


class Foo(BaseModel):
   bar: str

   @field_validator('bar', mode='before')
   @classmethod
   def validate_bar(cls, bar):
        return str(bar)
   

Foo(bar=1)
>>> Foo(bar='1')
```